# Job posting on other Stack Exchange sites

Tags: feature-request, support, jobs, job-offers

Is there any way of putting job posts on video.stackexchange.com? 
My workplace has a couple of video related jobs going, but I don't want to put them in the wrong place. I couldn't see anything in the rules related to this. What's the right way to do it?

Comment: Is it something that is being considered? Where would I suggest / propose it? Thanks!

Comment: Proposing it (or enquiring whether it's on the minds of the powers that be) right here on main Meta seems fine, as it might concern several sites on the network. It might be a dupe, though, not sure. In any case, you might want to tag this [feature-request] if you are to reshape your question into, well, a fetaure request.

Comment: A quick note for future users - Stack Exchange no longer has a [talent product](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293/674571)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Job listings are available through our [Talent product](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/); unfortunately, the service is only available on our Stack Overflow site at this time.

The reason this feature is currently centered on our largest site is simple [network effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_effect). Asking companies to list with us without the critical mass needed to assure results would be problematic; asking users to place their career efforts in a service without that employer-side supply would be a disaster.

**Unfortunately, we also cannot allow the posting of any type of solicitations** on our services. With so many projects and special interests vying for attention, soliciting support on the sites became unworkable pretty fast. Such activity would be 'flagged' and removed as spam.

You may want to contact our [advertising department](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/) to see if they have another option, but posting job listings on Stack Exchange sites is not allowed.